# How to prove that a set $A$ is a relation iff $A \subseteq \text{dom}(A) \times \text{ran}(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I tried to solve this using this method.

$$
\begin{align}
A &\subseteqq \text{dom}(A) \times \text{ran}(A) \\
&= \{x : \exists y ((x, y) \in A)\} \times \{y : \exists x ((x, y) \in A)\} \tag{By definition} \\
&= \{(a, b) : a \in \{x : \exists y ((x, y) \in A)\} \text{ and } b \in \times \{y : \exists x ((x, y) \in A)\}\} \tag{Def. cartesian product} \\
&= \{(a, b) : \exists y ((a, y) \in A) \text{ and } \exists x((x, b) \in A) \}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $A$ is a set of ordered pairs, and it is thus a relation.

But I'm unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Isn't *any* set of ordered pairs a relation? The assumption explicitly tells us that every element of $A$ is an ordered pair.

Comment: This is a weird question that seems to indicate you might be using some odd definition of 'relation.' Normally, a relation is a set $A$ such that there exists sets $B$ and $C$ such that $A\subseteq B\times C.$ But you've already got such sets, so it seems redundant to go any further. Perhaps the question meant to be an 'if and only if' proof? Then you'd want to show also if $A\subseteq B\times C,$ then also $A\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(A)\times\operatorname{ran}(A).$ That second is at least more than one step.

Comment: Also, is. $\subseteqq$ the same as $\subseteq?$

Comment: Yes (at least I think it is).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, I had indeed misread the question (it was an iff rather than an if).

Comment: It seems that $dom(A)$ and $ran(A)$ are only **defined** for relations $A$. So the question doesn't make  much sense.

Comment: I found the question in Enderton's "Elements of Set Theory" where they define a relation as a set of ordered pairs, and domain and range as I applied them in the question.